# Proving that $ \frac {\sin (n+1) \theta}{\sin \theta}=\sum \limits _{l=0}^{n} P_l(\cos \theta)P_{n-l}(\cos \theta)$

Tags: special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I am trying to prove that $$ \frac {\sin (n+1) \theta}{\sin \theta}=\sum \limits _{l=0}^{n} P_l(\cos \theta)P_{n-l}(\cos \theta)$$. I found this identity on wikipedia but I am unable to prove it. If anyone has any hints it would be great.

Comment: One definition of Legendre polynomials is through their OGF
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t\cos\theta+t^2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(\cos\theta) t^n$$
What's on your RHS is the coefficient of $t^n$ in $$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t\cos\theta + t^2}}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{1-2t\cos\theta + t^2} = \frac{1}{(1-te^{i\theta})(1 - t e^{-i\theta})} = \cdots$$

Comment: @achillehui thanks a lot got it